# Python wildcard search - blanks in between search words

Tags: wildcard

my first stackoverflow question. Would appreciate your input.

I'm trying to search for the following in a Google Finance web retrieve for GOOG stock utf-8 decoded and stored in a variable: (Trying to get the location of the stock price basically from 100s of lines of data.)

search words: `<meta itemprop="price"
        content="600.70"`

As you can see above there are several spaces after "price" and before "content". I tried using an asterix to replace the spaces as follows but it doesn't work. Is there a way around this?

```
m = re.search('<meta itemprop="price"*content="600.70"', variable)

print(m) -> None

m = re.search('<meta itemprop="price"( *)content="600.70"', variable)

print(m) -> None
```

I'm using Python 3.4.3

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use \s instead of the space (so it will match also newlines)
2. Prefix the string with r.
3. Add \ before the . (just to be accurate)

e.g.

```
 re.search(r'<meta itemprop="price"\s*content="600\.70"', variable)
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!
I didn't prefix with r though - just used \s* and it did the trick. Thanks again!